# How to add line breaks into icon file names?

Tags: inno-setup

Having an icon entry like this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\The Desktop Icon"; Filename: "{sys}\calc.exe"
```

I would like my icon to be named with one word per line irrespective of changing the icon view settings of the Windows Explorer (small, large, medium):

```
┌───────────┐
│    The    │
│  Desktop  │
│   Icon    │
└───────────┘
```

Is there a way to specify the link file name so that it will contain line breaks ?

Comment: What you can see in desktop's list view are names of the *.lnk files. Does common Windows file systems even support file names with line breaks (I don't think so, so I'd say that it's impossible to do what you want) ? Very interesting question anyway!

Comment: Thanks @TLama for your feedback, is there any we way out to get this done. I tried with [CustomMessages] SampleDesktopIcon=The %n Desktop %n Icon

Comment: First we must find out if the common Windows file systems (like e.g. NTFS) even supports line breaks in file names. And only if so, we can attempt to do something in Inno Setup.

Comment: I think when you see line breaks in filenames, you really are seeing spaces, and explorer brakes them into separate lines. AFAIK \n in file names is not allowed. Actually nothing below `Ord(' ')` is allowed according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Seems a tricky one. By our findings we can conclude its impossible to add line breaks. Thanks @mg30rg

Comment: @TLama I know. What I have meant is the new line character. You know `CR/LF`.

Comment: @mg30rg, I see. Sorry, I've been modifying my comment and deleted the old one. Yes, I see. I second you that it's not possible to escape a line break in file name.

Comment: @TLama - I did not say user should escape a line break in the file name. I only used the backslash escaped notation since `CR/LF` is/are non printing character(s). Sorry for being somewhat unclear.

Comment: @mg30rg, no worries :-) Well, to summarize this, newline (`CR/LF`) consists from two non-printable chars in the range of (for file naming conventions) invalid chars (char code 1-31), an thus it would have to be escaped somehow. And such line break escape could not use a single backslash because backslash is treated as a path component separator in file naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can see in Windows Explorer's desktop list view are names of the *.lnk files from desktop folders. So to force line breaks in that list view items you would need at least creating files containing line breaks in their names.

And that's what I think is impossible, at least because [`file naming convention`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) restricts the use of line break chars (`CR` and `LF` chars), since they are in a disallowed char code range 1-31 and so a line break would have to be escaped somehow and I believe that such escape would be described somewhere, but I cannot find any note about it.

Comment: What would be the point of trying to escape a character sequence which consists of a non-allowed character?

Comment: @Sertac, well, I didn't think of a real char escape, but a sequence which would produce a line break.

Comment: A line break wouldn't make it into a filename, however produced, because the characters make up one are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a No-Break Space (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0160) to pad the name.

Comment: This answer isn't what the question was asking, however, it helped me do exactly what the OP was wanting to do in another way.  Thank you.